# Resizing a div using CSS for mobile devices

Tags: css, html, mobile, mobile-devices

Is it possible to have a div resize for mobile devices using just CSS? If so could somebody please show me a working example so I can work out how to do it myself?

Thank you

Comment: And font resizing too, thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. But how do you want to resize them? *From* what *to* what? Without specifics all I can really do is point you to [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: Oh sorry David, it's basically a div I have fixed at the top of my website so as you scroll down it stays there, ithas text inside it, so it will be with a max width of 650px for iOS, from I guess a max width of 1024px

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use media query like below for particular device i.e phone, tab etc
Following is just example

**CSS**

```
.cont {float:left;width :400px;background-color:#000;}
.cont .left {float:left;width :200px;}
.cont .right {float:left;width :200px;}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */

.cont {width :200px; background-color:#666666 !important;}
.cont .left {width :100px !important;}
.cont .right {width :100px !important;}

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="left">
        left content
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        right content 
    </div> 
</div>
```

**Otherwise you can set width of div in percentage instead of pixel i.e**

```
.cont {float:left;width :100%;background-color:#000;}
.cont .left {float:left;width :50%;}
.cont .right {float:left;width :50%;}
```